# Creating agnostic cards outside inline editor using dialogflow

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I want to create cards in my Dialogflow webhook developed in Python. I know how to do it in the Inline Editor:

```
    agent.add(new Card({
        title: '*How has the COVID-19 crisis :mask:*',
        text: 'impacted the stability of your life?',
      })
    );
    agent.add(new Suggestion("1 :cold_sweat: *more exasperated and hopeless*"));
    agent.add(new Suggestion("2 :expressionless: *less freaked out than other people*"));
    agent.add(new Suggestion("3 :relieved: *More calm and hopeful*"));
    agent.add(new Suggestion("4 :fearful: *More scared and panicked*"));
    agent.add(new Suggestion("5 :smiley: *More surprised and baffled*"));
```

However I have to disallow the inline editor when using a self designed webhook. I don't know how to create the same card with button messages to use it on a self designed website, either from the app with Post request from my Flask app, or using the custom payload option.

How to create cards from custome payload or app from post requests?

My website is based on [this repository](https://github.com/dongido001/flask_chatbot)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [pydialogflow-fulfillment](https://pypi.org/project/pydialogflow-fulfillment/) module: it works with Flask and gives you an SDK to create the main response types (text response, suggested actions):

```
dialogflow_response.add(Suggestions(["Option 1","Option 2","Option 3"]))
```

Check out Flask sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/Emmarex/dialogflow-fulfillment-python)